# is it possible to import data to tally in xls format?

Tags: xml, tally

I am new to Tally Prime. I want to import data in tally in Xls.

I have imported data in XML format.

Is it possible to import data in tally in Xls format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Took me 2 minutes to find this: https://techguruplus.com/excel-to-tally-tdl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no direct way to import data to Tally from Excel(xls)
You can either convert excel data to xml using VBA or use Existing tools(Paid) like

- [Excel To Tally](http://store.accountingcompanion.com/product/excel-to-tally/) -- By AccountingCompanion.com